# Net-SNMP python binding path

Tags: macos, development, snmp

I'm currently setting a development environment in python 3.3 and i'm trying to import the Net-SNMP python bindings but idk where the files are located.

Simple question: anyone knows where are located the Net-SNMP python binding files in MacOSX 10.8.3??

Comment: I think you need to install them

Comment: @Mark well MacOSX comes with Net-SNMP pre-installed, then i need to download sources compile and install manually ?

Comment: Yes see [this blog](https://stomp.colorado.edu/blog/blog/2011/06/06/on-net-snmp-and-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python bindings for Net-SNMP are not built by default ([Net-SNMP docs](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Python_Bindings)) and are not part of the default install on OSX.

The can be installed from the Net-SNMP source code or via package managers such as macports.

Comment: only a comment. Mac ports doesn't have the Python Binding package. i used Mac Ports to install the most recent version of net-SNMP and downloaded the tar.gz from the official page and built manually the binding (both Macport Package and the Tarball are the same versions)

Comment: Try the py27-snmp port